# Simple number theory game, pt. 3

Tags: javascript, beginner, game

More refactoring based you guys' [great feedback](/q/102550). This time around I worked on using global/local variables properly and efficiently, putting return values to use, renaming variables so that the code is more understandable, and simplifying functions so that they serve one main purpose.

My main concerns/focuses now: I'm not sure that I like the global variable `newScoreAlertIndex` and how it's being implemented, and am working on how to better write the `newScoreAlert` function. Also, since the while loop can essentially be divided up into two structurally equivalent parts (the user's turn and the computer's turn), I was debating creating a function to run a full turn, and call it twice in the while loop, switching between user and computer factor/score parameters. However I felt like this blurred the line between query and command, so I left it as is. Let me know what you think.

```js
var welcome = alert("Welcome to Zeros or Ones! Both you and the computer will start the game off with the number '2'. Whoever gets down to '1' or '0' first wins!"),

rules = alert("This is a turn based game. You must first choose a factor from the computer's number. If the chosen factor is even, it is added to your current score; if odd, it is subtracted. After this, the computer chooses a factor from your new number. This back-and-forth continues until someone gets their number down to 1 or 0."),

rules2 = alert("A few exceptions:\n\nWhen an odd number is being subtracted from your score, if your resulting score is a negative number, the absolute value is taken, turning the negative number into a positive.\n\nNeither player is allowed to win the game on a 2. For instance if your score is 2, you cannot choose the factors 1 or 3 from the computer's score.\n\nException to the exception! In the case that you have a 2 and the computer has a 3, it is allowable to choose either factor.");


var compScore = 2,
    userScore = 2,
    operator,
    newScoreAlertIndex = 1;

function getFactors(integer) {
    var factors = [];
    for(var i = 1; i <= integer; i++){
        if(integer % i === 0){
            factors.push(i);
        }
    }
    return factors;
}

function getUserFactor() {
    var possibleFactors = getFactors(compScore);
    var factor;
    while (true) {
        factor = parseInt(prompt("Your score: " + userScore + ". Computer's score: " + compScore +  ". Which factor do you choose from the computer's score?"));
        if (possibleFactors.indexOf(factor) !== -1) {
            if (userScore !== 2 ||
            userScore === 2 && compScore === 3 ||
            userScore === 2 && compScore !== 3 && factor !== 1 && factor !== 3) {
                return factor;
            }
        }
        alert("Not a valid entry.");
    }
}

function getCompFactor() {
    var possibleFactors = getFactors(userScore);
    var factor = possibleFactors[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleFactors.length)];
    if (compScore === 2 && userScore !== 3) {
        while (factor === 1 || factor === 3) {
            factor = possibleFactors[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleFactors.length)];
        }
    }
    return factor;
}

function updateScore(chosenFactor, oldScore) {
    var newScore;
    if (chosenFactor % 2 === 0) {
        newScore = oldScore + chosenFactor;
        operator = "added to";
    } else {
        newScore = oldScore - chosenFactor;
        if (newScore < 0) {
            newScore = newScore * -1;
        }
        operator = "subtracted from";
    }
    return newScore;
}

function newScoreAlert(chosenFactor, operator, newScore) {
    var alertText;
    if (newScoreAlertIndex % 2 !== 0) { alertText = " your score. You now have "; }
    else { alertText = " the computer's score. The computer now has "; }
    alert(chosenFactor + " was " + operator + alertText + newScore + ".");
    newScoreAlertIndex += 1;
}

function checkForWin(number) {
    if (number === 1 || number === 0) { return true; }
    else { return false; }
}


while(true) {

    var userFactor = getUserFactor();
    userScore = updateScore(userFactor, userScore);
    newScoreAlert(userFactor, operator, userScore);
    if (checkForWin(userScore)) {
        alert("YAY! You won! :D");
        break;
    }

    var compFactor = getCompFactor();
    compScore = updateScore(compFactor, compScore);
    newScoreAlert(compFactor, operator, compScore);
    if (checkForWin(compScore)) {
        alert("Sorry! You lost :/");
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Already said, but maybe I was not clear. `var welcome = alert ...` means that welcome is assigned to None. Remove everything before the `=`. Replace `if cond return true else return false`

Comment: Just a note to say that you absolutely _can_ blur the line between command and query when it's expedient to do so. It's more something to keep in mind when coding; a "code smell". If a function is doing both things, maybe there's a better way. But don't make a huge detour just for the sake of it. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation) mentions the `pop` method, common to stacks and arrays, as an example: It both returns the last element _and_ removes it from the stack/array. Sure you could do that with 2 separate calls, but it's more useful as it is.

Comment: @Flambino nice point, blind obedience to a rule (regardless of its correctness) will not make your code magically better.

Answer (score 6):

A few suggestions to make your code more readable/succinct:

**1. Why not store your alerts in a single array?**

```
var alerts = [alert("....",
              alert("....",...`
```

This makes your code more maintainable and your variable names less arbitrary. We have to agree `rules2` is not such a hot name for a variable.

Note I don't  know if the syntax I have above is correct. You might need to use `bind` or `apply` or something so the `alert` doesn't execute right away, but you can easily check this with a fast experiment...

Note in comments below SirPython has clarified that storing them this way *will* immediately run them. Consider his suggestion of storing the messages in an array rather than an `alert` function itself.

**2. `getFactors` does a lot of unnecessary checks**

It's well known that to get the factors of a number, you only need to check numbers less than its square root. That's, by definition, the largest factor a number can have other than itself. So you can adjust the `for loop` like so:

```
check_lim = Math.floor(sqrt(integer)) + 1   
for(var i = 1; i< check_lim; i++) { 
   if(integer % i == 0){
       factors.push(i);
       factors.push(integer/i);
```

Relatedly, I'd also suggest changing `integer` to something that sounds less like a key/reserved word. Makes me nervous!

Also, now your factors won't be in order from smallest to greatest. If an ordered factor list is necessary for your code, and if you really are just sticking with small numbers, your present method could be better.

**3. Keep control statements as simple as possible**

I'd rewrite `checkForWin` like so:

```
function checkForWin(number) {
    return ( number === 1  || number === 0 );
}
```

Comment: The `getFactors` thing isn't quite right. Take 16 as an example; your code would return factors `[1, 2]`. It skips 4 because the for loop should use `<= check_lim`, but it also neglects 8. That's a valid factor too

Comment: @Flambino thanks for catching that. have updated the code accordingly.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you'll still miss 8 as a factor of 16. You have 2 as a factor of 16 already, but you also need its "counterpart", which is 8. So you basically have to loop all the way. Or get creative, and add both divisor and quotient to list of factors, but for square numbers you risk ending up with duplicates (e.g. 4 and 4 for 16) so that's another check. Looping the whole thing is just a pretty straight-forward way of doing things (esp. as we're not talking about huge numbers here)

Comment: @Flambino yes I will make it explicit instead of just .... for the for loop. I still think it's good practice to learn not to test unnecessary cases.

Comment: Oh, I agree, certainly. I too suggested a change to that same function in the first version of this question, for the very same reasons (and the result is in the question now). But I didn't go further than just a simple loop, since there was other stuff to review too. One step at a time and all that.

Comment: @Flambino ahhh I did not look at the prior versions. So perhaps OP has a strong preference for the original version in any case!

Comment: I have a preference for whichever version is best! I believe that Flambino was saying the original version of the function could use quite a few improvements, but he figured it best to go slow and first offer a small improvement that the beginner here could comprehend ;) but that he agrees with the good practice of not testing unnecessary cases

Comment: But anyways, thank you for the feedback! I'm a bit tied up now with other work, but I will definitely amend the function when I sit down to work on it again. It makes sense that, in more memory-intensive scenarios, finding the least intensive way to do things is best. I will keep that in mind from now on :) thank you. Also, I like to think that I learn relatively quickly, so feel free to go 2 or maybe even 3 steps at a time, I'll catch up :)

Comment: @Chris Heh, I wasn't metering out advice on purpose. I just didn't spend a lot of time on that function because in the grand scheme of things, there were more important things to tackle, and the function was good enough™ after a few changes. You can always come back to it. And now that the rest of the code is shaping up, it's a good time to do exactly what sunny did here and dig a little deeper.

Comment: I completely disagree about your first point. First of all, when that array is created, all those `alert`s are run immediately. Second of all, it is not very common at all in JavaScript to store all the messages printed out to the user in an array. However, if you are going to go with that approach, I recommend that you store them in an object. Then, when they are needed, you can just access like, for example, `alert(messages.UserWon);`

Comment: @SirPython I did note that storing the alerts in that form might immediately call them - that's why I told the OP he'd have to try it. I like your idea of just storing the messages...it's true there's no particular reason to save `alert()` as a function itself. Whether this is common to do is JavaScript doesn't need to be the main point. You'd also agree that it's not common in JavaScript to have var rules, var rules2 no?

Comment: @sunny Yes, I completely agree about not having the `rules` variables; there is no point in storing an `alert`...

Answer (score 5):

You've gotten rid of a lot of global variables, but you can do even better!

Consider writing this function:

```
function playGame(player, computer) {
   # start playing the game with initial scores: player, computer
   while (true) {
     var userFactor = getUserFactor(computer);
     ...
     var compFactor = getCompFactor(player);
     ...
   }
}
```

The main difference is that `getUserFactor(...)` and `getCompFactor(...)` now take an argument instead of referencing global variables.

Also, do the same with `newScoreAlertIndex`...

```
function playGame(player, computer) {
  var newScoreAlertIndex = 0;
  ...
  newScoreAlert(userFactor, operator, userScore, newScoreAlert);
  newScoreAlertIndex++;
  ...
}
```

The changes are:

1. Make `newScoreAlertIndex` a local variable.
2. Pass it into `newScoreAlert`.
3. Modify it in the main loop outside of `newScoreAlert`.

In fact, you should be able to find a way to eliminate the need for this variable - during the player's turn it is always odd and during the computer's turn it is always even.

Answer (score 4):

A few things that you can improve on:

---

### `alert`:

- There's no need to declare alerts as variables as:

  1. You don't use them.
  2. They return nothing.

- Don't have long lines of text, seperate the sentences into lines, like the following:

```
alert("Welcome to Zeros or Ones! "
    + "Both you and the computer will start the game off with the number '2'. "
    + "Whoever gets down to '1' or '0' first wins!");

alert("This is a turn based game. "
    + "You must first choose a factor from the computer's number. "
    + "If the chosen factor is even, it is added to your current score; if odd, it is subtracted. "
    + "After this, the computer chooses a factor from your new number. "
    + "This back-and-forth continues until someone gets their number down to 1 or 0.");

alert("A few exceptions:" + "\n\n"
    + "When an odd number is being subtracted from your score, if your resulting score is a negative number, the absolute value is taken, turning the negative number into a positive." + "\n\n"
    + "Neither player is allowed to win the game on a 2. "
    + "For instance if your score is 2, you cannot choose the factors 1 or 3 from the computer's score." + "\n\n"
    + "Exception to the exception! "
    + "In the case that you have a 2 and the computer has a 3, it is allowable to choose either factor.");
```

Notice that I seperated out the new-lines as well, that helps for readability also.

---

### Data Structure:

Consider turning your data structure of defined variables into a `data` object, like so:

```
var data = {
      computer_score: 2
    , user_score: 2
    , operator
    , new_score_alert_index: 1
}
```

---

### `getUserFactor`:

- You can simplify the following:

> ```
> var possibleFactors = getFactors(compScore);
> var factor;
> ```

into:

```
var possibleFactors = getFactors(compScore),
    factor;
```

- The long `parseInt` & `alert` call should be spread over multiple lines, like the `alert`s mentioned before:

> ```
>     factor = parseInt(prompt("Your score: " + userScore + ". Computer's score: " + compScore +  ". Which factor do you choose from the computer's score?"));
> ```

```
    factor = parseInt(
                prompt("Your score: "
                    + userScore
                    + ". Computer's score: "
                    + compScore
                    + ". Which factor do you choose from the computer's score?"
                    )
             );
```

- You should move the or operator in the `if` statement to the beginning of the new-lines:

```
if (userScore !== 2
    || userScore === 2 && compScore === 3
    || userScore === 2 && compScore !== 3 && factor !== 1 && factor !== 3) {
    return factor;
}
```

---

### `getCompFactor`:

- As you're testing whether `factor` is one of \$n\$ options, you can just make an array with all \$n\$ options, and ask whether `factor` is in it:

> ```
> while (factor === 1 || factor === 3) {
> ```

into:

```
while (factor in [1, 3]) {
```

---

### `UpdateScore`:

- You do not need to multiply `newScore` by negative one to return the negative value, just return the negative value:

> ```
> newScore = newScore * -1;
> ```

into:

```
newScore = -newScore;
```

---

### `newScoreAlert`:

- Instead of `if-else` blocks to assign `alertText`, use a ternary:

> ```
> var alertText;
> if (newScoreAlertIndex % 2 !== 0) { alertText = " your score. You now have "; }
> else { alertText = " the computer's score. The computer now has "; }
> ```

into:

```
var alertText = (newScoreAlertIndex % 2 !== 0
    ? " your score. You now have "
    : " the computer's score. The computer now has ");
```

- You should spread the `alert` call out over a few lines:

> ```
> alert(chosenFactor+ " was " + operator + alertText + newScore + ".");
> ```

into:

```
alert(chosenFactor
    + " was "
    + operator
    + alertText
    + newScore
    + ".");
```

- You don't need to `+= 1` or `-= 1`, you can use `++` and `--` respectively:

> ```
> newScoreAlertIndex +1;
> ```

into:

```
newScoreAlertIndex++;
```

---

### `checkForWin`:

- You can *heavily* simplify this function, because you can `return` a boolean condition, so, the following could be simplified:

> ```
> function checkForWin(number) {
>     if (number === 1 || number === 0) { return true; }
>     else { return false; }
> }
> ```

into:

```
function checkForWin(number) {
    return (number in [0, 1]);
}
```

Notice the `in` operator testing whether the `number` is in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of good answers already. I just want to look at one thing in particular, namely the way the computer chooses a factor.

You have these lines:

```
if (compScore === 2 && userScore !== 3) {
    while (factor === 1 || factor === 3) {
        factor = possibleFactors[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleFactors.length)];
    }
}
```

My issue is with the `while` loop. This is really just a theoretical concern, but there's a (astronomically unlikely) possibility that the loop runs *forever* - or at least, runs for a loooong time - because it randomly keeps picking 1 or 3 over and over again. Or it picks a winner first time out, and it's not a problem. But the point is that you don't know.

Again, it's not a practical concern, but in terms of abstract "correctness" it's a concern.

I'd recommend simply removing those two factors from the list, so they won't be picked to begin with. Of course, this requires more code, but it does make the whole thing more correct.

A simple filter implementation would be something like:

```
var allowedFactors = factors.filter(function (factor) {
  return factor !== 1 && factor !== 3;
});
```

Of course it's still only relevant if the computer's score is 2 and the user's score isn't 3.

You can make it more generic, in case your rules change again, and you have to blacklist arbitrary factors:

```
function filterFactors(factors, excluded) {
  return factors.filter(function (factor) {
    return excluded.indexOf(factor) === -1;
  });
}

// usage:
var allowed = filterFactors(factors, [1, 3]);
```